# Security Exception while accessing the "StartupNormalAppListActivity" Huawei Phone

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

My app is getting SecurityEception on a Huawei device (Huawei P30 Pro, Android 10, EMUI 11.0.0Version), while accessing StartupNormalAppListActivity. Below is stacktrace and exception.

I have tired multiple ways but couldn't find the solution for the same.

**Package name**: com.huawei.systemmanager

**Class Name**: com.huawei.systemmanager.appcontrol.activity.StartupAppControlActivity

@Note: I have added the permission in the manifest file

**Exception:**

FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 31462
**java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { cmp=com.huawei.systemmanager/.startupmgr.ui.StartupNormalAppListActivity } from ProcessRecord{6350b78 31462:com.example.myapplication/u0a298} (pid=31462, uid=10298) requires com.huawei.permission.external_app_settings.USE_COMPONENT**
at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2071)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2039)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1987)
at android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub$Proxy.startActivity(IActivityTaskManager.java:3888)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1738)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5368)

Comment: what permission did you declare? Can you, please, add your `AndroidManifest` here?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.permission.external_app_settings.USE_COMPONENT" />

Comment: @NikhilReddy did you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add `android:exported="true"` to the activity field in your AndroidManifest.xml file.